# Big Query: Create table with time partitioning and clustering fields using Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I can successfully create a Big Query table in Python as:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

bq_client = bigquery.Client()
table_name = "my_test_table"

dataset = bq_client.dataset("MY_TEST_DATASET")
table_ref = dataset.table(table_name)
table = bigquery.Table(table_ref)
table = bq_client.create_table(table)
```

And later I upload a local Pandas DataFrame as:

```
# --- Define BQ options ---
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND"
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV

# --- Load data ---
job = bq_client.load_table_from_dataframe(
        df, f"MY_TEST_DATASET.{table_name}", job_config=job_config
    )
```

How can I specify, while creating the table and using Python:

1. Partition by daily ingestion time
2. As clustering fields ["business_id", "software_house", "product_id"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `Python` script to create your `BigQuery` table with partitioning and clustering :

```py
def create_table():
    from google.cloud import bigquery

    # Construct a BigQuery client object.
    client = bigquery.Client()

    table_id = "your_project.your_dataset.table_test"

    schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField("business_id", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("software_house", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("product_id", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("other_field", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("ingestion_time", "TIMESTAMP", mode="NULLABLE"),
    ]

    table = bigquery.Table(table_id, schema=schema)

    # Clustering.
    table.clustering_fields = ["business_id", "software_house", "product_id"]

    # Partitioning.
    table.time_partitioning = bigquery.TimePartitioning(
        type_=bigquery.TimePartitioningType.DAY,
        field="ingestion_time",  # name of column to use for partitioning
        expiration_ms=7776000000
    )  # 90 days

    table = client.create_table(table)
    print(
        "Created table {}.{}.{}".format(table.project, table.dataset_id, table.table_id)
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_table()
```

In this case :

- A partitoning was added on `ingestion_time` field per DAY
- A clustering wad added on ["business_id", "software_house", "product_id"] fields

These docs show how adding partitioning and clustering on fields :

- [BQ table partitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables)
- [BQ table clustering](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-clustered-tables)

The result in `BigQuery` is :

[image]

Comment: Thank you; is it possible to create a table with clustering an time partitioning but without a schema? And auto-detect the latter when uploading the first DataFrame @Mazlum

Comment: If you want using autodetect, you need to do everything in the program that loading your csv file to `BigQuery` :

With Dataframe : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-table-dataframe

Directly with Python client : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect

You have to be carreful with autodetect, sometimes the generated type is different than expected and we have less control on field types.

Comment: I think it's better to create your table with a schema and load csv file with `CREATE_NEVER` `BigQuery` option.